# Pathogen helptags not generating

Tags: vim, pathogen

I know there is a lot of questions about the :Helptags Pathogen command, but I just can't find the answer to this particular problem anywhere.

When I run the :Helptags command in Vim, it just jumps out from the command line, up to NerdTree or the file currently open.

My /.vim folder structure, on my Mac is like this:

```
" Press ? for help             |
                               |~                                                                                  
.. (up a dir)                  |~                                                                                  
/Users/Mikkel/.vim/            |~                                                                                  
▾ autoload/                    |~                                                                                  
    pathogen.vim               |~                                                                                  
▾ bundle/                      |~                                                                                  
  ▾ neocomplete.vim/           |~                                                                                  
    ▸ autoload/                |~                                                                                  
    ▾ doc/                     |~                                                                                  
        neocomplete.txt [RO]   |~                                                                                  
    ▸ plugin/                  |~                                                                                  
    ▸ test/                    |~                                                                                  
      CONTRIBUTING.md [RO]     |~                                                                                  
      README.md [RO]           |~                                                                                  
  ▾ nerdtree/                  |~                                                                                  
    ▸ autoload/                |~                                                                                  
    ▾ doc/                     |~                                                                                  
        NERD_tree.txt [RO]     |~                                                                                  
    ▸ lib/                     |~                                                                                  
    ▸ nerdtree_plugin/         |~                                                                                  
    ▸ plugin/                  |~                                                                                  
    ▸ syntax/                  |~                                                                                  
      CHANGELOG [RO]           |~                                                                                  
      LICENCE [RO]             |~                                                                                  
      README.markdown [RO]     |~                                                                                  
  ▾ tagbar/                    |~                                                                                  
    ▸ autoload/                |~                                                                                  
    ▾ doc/                     |~                                                                                  
        tagbar.txt [RO]        |~                                                                                  
    ▸ plugin/                  |~                                                                                  
    ▸ syntax/                  |~                                                                                  
      LICENSE [RO]             |~                                                                                  
      README.md [RO]           |~                                                                                  
  ▾ vim-go/                    |~                                                                                  
    ▸ autoload/                |~                                                                                  
    ▸ compiler/                |~                                                                                  
    ▾ doc/                     |~                                                                                  
        vim-go.txt [RO]        |~                                                                                  
    ▸ ftdetect/
```

If I go with Vims standard :helptags  command, it appends a folder named "tags" to the folder I'm trying to generate docs from.

```
E152: Cannot open /Users/Mikkel/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/doc/tags for writing
```

I've spent 4 hours now, trying to find a solution to this, without any luck.

Comment: Why are all those files marked as "read only"?

Comment: @romainl That's actually a very good question. It's probably because I had to use sudo to clone the repos into the folder. I didn't even notice that. I'll try changing it and post the result here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot, and didn't have the correct permissions for the files in the docs. I did `chmod 774 <filename>` on all the txt files, and everything works like a charm.

Thanks to @romainl for pointing it out